# How do I force a button to the right in a horizontal linear layout with another button to the left of it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 buttons (left and right) side by side in a linear layout (horizontal). I want left to take all of the space if right is blank. If right has content, I want it to stick to the right and then left fills as much of the remaining space that it can. How do I do this?

Pretty sure I have to use linear layout because a relative layout will cause overlap.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button            
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"   
        android:text="this text takes priority and kicks everything off screen (not desired behavior)" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>  

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
        android:text="i need this text to take priority over the other button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why not use weights like you did with the view?

Comment: When you say "if right is blank" do you mean button text? Is it something you are controlling by code?

Comment: @SalmanTariq yeah that works but what if I want the button on the right to not show if it has no text in it? I would have to do that programmatically right?

Comment: Or make it gone in layout and make it visible when you are setting text (if any)

Comment: `android:layout_gravity="end"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RelativeLayout` will work well for this. By anchoring both buttons to their respective sides with `alignParent`, and positioning the first button to the left of the second with `toLeftOf`  – you'll achieve a flexible left button, that will not overlap the right button.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"
        android:text="Left Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Right Button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the critical line to prevent overlap is "android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button2"". thanks, didnt know that

Comment: Thanks for updating your comment, please mark this correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achievable by relative layout and is always recommended to use relative layout. Just make view for left first and make is wrap content and make another view with match parent respectively.

Comment: what do you mean make the right "match parent"? wouldn't that cause overlap?

Comment: if you know relative layout better than we can handle every thing by stating that this view is right of this, or this view is strictly in right or left and who comes after what, etc.